# Can't convert response to valid typescript value for strore

Tags: angular, typescript

I described these interfaces:

```
enum ProductType {current, closed, coming}

export interface CurrentProductForCarousel {
 type_product:ProductType.current;
 offers: ProductMainInfo[]
}

export interface ProductMainInfo {
  id: number;
  disclaimer: string;
  company?: {
    registeredOfficeState?: string;
  };
  date: {
    timestamp: number;
    days: number;
    hours: number;
  };
}
```

I have ngrx-store. My reducer looks like

```
export interface State {
 currentProductForCarousel: CurrentProductForCarousel | null;
}

export const initialState: State = {
 сurrentProductForCarousel: null,
};

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: 
pruduct.Actions): State {
 switch (action.type) {
  case pruductActions.FETCH_PRODUCTS_CURRENT_SUCCESS: {
    return {
      ...state,
    currentProductsForCarousel: action.payload,
    };
  }
```

Example of response

```
{"success":true, "type_prudct":"current","products":[{"id":34, "disclaimer": "text", "company":{"registeredOfficeSuburb":"West Perth"}, "date":{"timestamp":1567987198,"days":710,"hours":"14"}}]}
```

Question is how i can set response data with correct type of my interface to store and than get data from store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type in your response doesn't match the enum, as it is a string. You can represent it as below though:

```
type ProductType = 'current' | 'closed' | 'coming';

interface Company {
    registeredOfficeSuburb: string;
}

interface ProductDate {
    timestamp: number;
    days: number;
    hours: string;
}

interface Product {
    id: number;
    disclaimer: string;
    company: Company;
    date: ProductDate;
}

interface ProductResponse {
    success: boolean;
    type_prudct: ProductType,
    products:Product[]
}

var r: ProductResponse = {
    "success": true,
    "type_prudct": "current",
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 34,
            "disclaimer": "text",
            "company": { "registeredOfficeSuburb": "West Perth" },
            "date": { "timestamp": 1567987198, "days": 710, "hours": "14" }
        }]
};
```